# Binning numeric variable to categorical, but appear to have lots of NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to bin this numeric variable into three categories, but after the binning, I got lots of NaNs. Could anyone tell me how to fix the issue.

The bin should be

```
1-2000
2000-8000
8000-35797
```

Code:

```
df_all['df_newcol'] = pd.cut(df.sales, bins = [1, 2000, 8000,35797], labels=['Low', 'Mid', 'High'])
df_all['df_newcol']
```

```
0           NaN
1           NaN
2           NaN
3          High
4          High
           ... 
3968995     NaN
3968996     NaN
3968997     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I creared the following source DataFrame (*df*):

```
    sales
10    200
12   2000
14   2001
16   7999
18   8000
20   8001
22  12000
```

Binning it **alone** returns:

```
10     Low
12     Low
14     Mid
16     Mid
18     Mid
20    High
22    High
Name: sales, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Low < Mid < High]
```

So far, OK.

Then I defined *df_all* with the following content:

```
    xxxx
8    100
10   120
11   130
12   140
13   150
14   160
16   170
17   180
18   190
19   200
30   210
32   230
```

Note that it:

- contains some "extra" index values (absent in *df*),
- does **not** contain some index values from *df* (namely *20* and *22*).

Now when you save the binning result in *df_all*, and print the
new column, the result is:

```
8     NaN
10    Low
11    NaN
12    Low
13    NaN
14    Mid
16    Mid
17    NaN
18    Mid
19    NaN
30    NaN
32    NaN
Name: df_newcol, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [Low < Mid < High]
```

As you can see, it **does** contain some *NaN*s.

The reason is that the result of *cut* is **adjusted** to the index
of the target DataFrame, i.e.:

- Rows with keys absent in *df* receive *NaN*.
- Values with keys absent in *df_all* are lost.

And probably just this case happened in your environment.
Apparently *df_all* contains some extra indices, compared to *df*
and they have been given *NaN*s.

## Edit

*df* can also contain values **outside** the given set of bins and
the binning result for such rows is **also** *NaN*.

Comment: Is there anyway to solve this problem. I used another server (envrionment) to run this. Same issue happened.